# Problem with "shapes arrow" in TikZ+LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

When I used the following example to print a shape arrow

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.arrows} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [single arrow,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=2cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the following error happened:

```
./arrow.tex:6:Package tikz Error: I do not know what to do with the option ``single arrow''. ...arrow,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=2cm]
```

Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: You might be using an old version of PGF/TikZ. You can find out what version you are using by putting `\pgfversion` after `\begin{document}`. It should be at least v 2.10. Note also that you need to use `draw` in the node options, otherwise you will not see the outline of the shape.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there any alternatives?

Comment: The single best thing you can do is to upgrade your PGF package. Version 2.1 brings a lot of really important improvements, so even if you found a way to do without it right now, you would run into issues down the road that would force you to upgrade anyway.

Comment: @Jake: Could you please add this as an answer.

Comment: Since it works with a current version of TikZ (and the additional `draw` option) the question will be closed as too localized.

Answer (score 2):

The single best thing you can do is to upgrade your PGF package. Version 2.1 brings a lot of really important improvements, so even if you found a way to do without it right now, you would run into issues down the road that would force you to upgrade anyway.